# Command prompt pops up and closes

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

My command prompt opens up randomly for like 10 seconds and then closes. The title says `npm`. I don't know what is causing it or how to solve it. Do you guys have any ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing happening...Not sure why no one can offer an explanation..